# How to determine if a cv::Mat has any zero values?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I've got a "mask" image, and I need to know if it has any zero values. I'd like to do something equivalent to:

```
bool HasMissingPixels(const cv::Mat& mask) {
     return cv::countNonZero(image) < mask.rows * mask.cols;
}
```

It feels like wasting computation to find **all** (non-)zeros, when it could return true as soon as the **first** zero pixel is encountered. On the other hand, by iterating over the pixels myself I lose the advantage of `OpenCV`'s optimization, parallelization etc.

Is there a way to compute this faster?

Comment: what about adapting opencv Code of countNonZero and compile it right with openCV? Should give you the same kind of optimizations. I don't know a "cv::hasZeroValues"-like function, but maybe that's just a lack of knowledge :)

Comment: _"It feels like..."_ please profile before making assumptions

Comment: @Miki - true that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It usually makes sense to optimize for the worst case ("there is no zero value element in the array"), as then your system will have a predictable runtime behavior. Thus using `countNonZero` or `minMaxLoc` are good functions to achieve your goal here.

Whether an iterative approach that breaks early could be faster depends completely on the data ("are there zero values early in the matrix in the majority of the cases?"). You will find no such function in a library like OpenCV, as the library maintainer doesn't know your data and couldn't write code that optimizes for your custom data distribution.